# How do I get text value from specific tag with specific classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get value `7` which is within the `active` classname?. Below is sample code:

```
<ul id="pageList">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the right selector and the `text()` method:

```
var foo = $('#pageList .active a').text(); // = '7'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following.

```
var text = $('li.active > a').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the text without jQuery

```
var activePageNo = document.querySelector("#pageList .active a").textContent;
```

Note: this code will work on all modern browsers and IE>7

Answer (score 1):

Try using bellow

```
var pageNo=$(".active").text();
```